# Meteor & TypeScript - Error: The property 'confirm' does not exist on value of type '{}'

Tags: meteor, typescript, nitrousio, meteor-accounts, typescript1.4

I'm developing a web application with Meteor and TypeScript, also using the Nitrous.io environment.

I'm trying to implement a user account system. I'm adapting JavaScript code which I had in my old project (it worked), but I'm still getting errors. This is from the *login.ts* file:

```
// retrieve the input field values
        var email = template.$('[name=email]').val();
        var password = template.$('[name=password]').val();

        var errors = {};

        if (! email) {
            errors.email = 'Please enter your email address';     // ERROR HERE
        }

        if (! password) {
            errors.password = 'Please enter your password';       // ERROR HERE
        }
```

The error messages I'm getting are:

```
/client/login.ts(41,20): error TS2094: The property 'email' does not exist on value of type '{}'.                                                                                                                                           

/client/login.ts(45,20): error TS2094: The property 'password' does not exist on value of type '{}'.
```

Any ideas? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the errors object to this.

```
var errors = {
   email:"",
   password:""
};
```

You can also throw the error object (wich on every browser support this 2 properties)

1. name  - The name of the error
2. message - A description of the error

or a custom error.

```
if (! email) {
            throw new Error('Please enter your email address')     // ERROR HERE
        }

        if (! password) {
            throw new Error('Please enter your password')       // ERROR HERE
        }
```

Check [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/03/10/the-art-of-throwing-javascript-errors-part-2/) if you interested on throwing errors